# How do I remove Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - Gem install error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, installation

I am trying to install create a new app in Ruby on Rails and I cannot get passed this error:

```
$ gem install pg
```

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
>       Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/stormyramsey/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.21.0/.gemtest

Comment: Try with `sudo gem install pg`.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma: `sudo` ought to be unnecessary if the goal is to install the gem under ~/.rbenv. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @StormyRamsey, Who owns `/stormyramsey/.rbenv/`? Is it the `root` user?

Answer (score 58):

Its a permissions issue. You could fix it with this:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Library/Ruby/Gems/*
```

or possibly in your case

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Users/stormyramsey/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/*
```

**What does this do:**

This is telling the system to change the files to change the ownership to the current user. Something must have gotten messed up when something got installed. Usually this is because there are multiple accounts or users are using sudo to install when they should not always have to.

Comment: could you explain what exactly is the issue?

Comment: Updated my answer with the explanation

Answer (score 11):

No need to change permission, just export GEM_HOME:

```
export GEM_HOME="$HOME/.gem"
```

Comment: @Stormy Ramsey, please, if you agree, this answer should be labeled as the one that solved the issue.

Answer (score 10):

It's likely there's a permissions problem somewhere along the .rbenv path. You might try turning on write privileges for your user with:

```
$ chmod -R +w ~/.rbenv
```

That will recursively (`-R`) change the file mode (`chmod`) to write permission (`+w`) for all files and directories under your user's .rbenv path. There's no particular reason for not having files set to write.

Answer (score 4):

For Mac M1 systems try,

1. Allowing full disk access to terminal.

   Apple->systemPreferences->Security&Privacy->privacy(Tab)->'+' button, check in Terminal application.
   Then Restart terminal
   2.Try using,

   sudo chflags noschg

Comment: Thanks. PS - You forgot after the `privacy(tab)` to click `Full Disk Access` on the left

Answer (score 2):

Delete the pod folder, reinstall it again. If it doesn't work use this command:

```
sudo pod install --allow-root
```

Comment: This flag is very risky, avoid at all cost.

Answer (score 0):

It really doesn't matter on mac how you configure your eyaml create the dir and config manually, add some public key location to it, and its works just fine after adding full disk access to the terminal as Kewin suggested ^ ^. Thumbs up.

Answer (score -1):

please run:

```
sudo gem install pg
```