# Rails installs but I get 'Rails is not currently installed on this system' error when I try to use it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems

I'm pretty deep into a project, I have deployed a version of it on heroku which demanded I update my ruby version to complete my setup. After successfully completing that process I went back to my project to continue development and tried to save some variables using

```
EDITOR='code --wait' rails credentials:edit
```

and I get...

```
➜  $EDITOR='code --wait' rails credentials:edit

=> Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

When I run the sudo command I get successful response but when I try to run EDITOR='code --wait' rails credentials:edit I get the same error.

I've tried to work through some solutions which lead me to try

```
gem install rails
```

but then I get this error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rails-6.1.3.2/README.md
```

As I can not save the variable or even start a new rails project I am pretty much stuck and will appreciate any suggestions or guidance.

Comment: How did you install Ruby?

Comment: I used `rbenv install`

Comment: Try updating the gems folder owner to your current user `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems`.

Comment: Looks like you've screwed up permissions with `sudo`. Since you're using `rbenv`, you should not need to run any ruby/gem installation commands with `sudo`.

Comment: You could either try to fix all files/folders that you've messed up (as per the above suggestion), or completely uninstall ruby, then re-install it cleanly without `sudo`.

Comment: I guess I'll uninstall it completely as the other solution still ends plays out like this:                                                  `   ~  gem install rails

Successfully installed rails-6.1.3.2
1 gem installed
                                                                                               ~ rails -v
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails`

Comment: Does this seem like a good set of instructions to follow?  [link] (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-macos)

Comment: This may be discussed already but the fact that your permission denied error is referencing a path in `/usr/local/lib/ruby` tells me that your call to `gem` is not using the `gem` executable provided by `rbenv`, so you should investigate your installation of `rbenv` and check that it has been correctly installed. To confirm you should be able to run  `which gem` and get a path that points to a location within your `rbenv` installation directory, typically `~/.rbenv/shims/gem`.

Comment: @taylorthurlow when I run `which gem` I get `/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/gem` I have very little experience with this realm and have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove Permission denied @ rb\_sysopen - Gem install error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770882/how-do-i-remove-permission-denied-rb-sysopen-gem-install-error)

Comment: @jsonmullings You should read the documentation for `rbenv`: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#how-it-works