# zsh: permission denied: /Users/..; gem install rails ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES) Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, permission-denied

I have a course this weekend where we´re learning to use ruby on rails. We were supposed to install everything for it and then run "gem install rails" to check, if it worked (I guess).
If I do so, I just get the following error:
gem install rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/..
I already tried to uninstall everything, but after installing it again I still get the same error. Can someone help me please?

Also if I try to copy any dokument into my terminal, I always get the error: zsh: permission denied: /Users/..

I am total beginner and right now have no idea what I´m doing, so please be kind if it is a stupid question:D

Thanks in advance
Anna

Comment: This related question might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770882/how-do-i-remove-permission-denied-rb-sysopen-gem-install-error

Comment: Yes thanks. That solved it!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove Permission denied @ rb\_sysopen - Gem install error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770882/how-do-i-remove-permission-denied-rb-sysopen-gem-install-error)